# How to add quotes to all elements at once in a list/tuple using the keyboard (keyboard shortcut)

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

if I have a tuple `(red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, white, cyan)` and want to have each element as a string `("red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "white", "cyan")`, is there a keyboard shortcut to add double quotes to all elements at once. This would save me a lot of time in case the list/tuple is long and needs to contain strings. Looking specifically VS code or Sublime text shortcuts on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could solve this is by using find-and-replace with regular expression mode enabled.

## Warning, this can be dangerous

If you are *absolutely certain* that each element is *imediatelly* followed by either a comma or `)`

```regex
// Find
([^,\s]+)([,)])

// Replace by
"$1"$2
```

Make sure to check each occurrence manually to avoid replacing things that shouldn't be!
This will vary wildly depending on how the tuple is literally typed.